# Common syntax for declaring and initializing constexpr on MSVC and GCC

Tags: c++

```
namespace MyNS {
    template <>
    class Test<Test1> {
        public:
            constexpr static char const *description[] = { "X`", "Y1"};
        /*
        ...
        ...
        */
    } 
    constexpr char const * Test<Test1>::description[]; 
    /* Above definition is required when compiling with GCC but MSVC compiler gives error saying 'description' is redeclared.  */
    /* **Omitting definition of 'description', which is written outside class in namespace, causes successful compilation by MSVC but failure in GCC** */ 
}
```

Is there a **common way to define, declare and initialize above constexpr** such that **code compiles successfully by both MSVC and GCC**?

Comment: g++ Version? MSVC Version? Compiler options? [mcve]?

Comment: Works fine at http://ideone.com/JDY1rU. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace MyNS {
    template<class T> struct Test;
    template <>
    struct Test<int> {
        constexpr static char const * description[] = { "X1", "Y1"};
    };
}
int main() {
    std::cout << MyNS::Test<int>::description[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles -as far as I can tell- using

- `g++-4.8+ -std=c++11`
- `g++-4.8+ -std=c++1y`
- `g++-4.9+ -std=c++14`
- `g++-6.1+`
- `g++-6.1+ -std=c++11`
- `g++-6.1+ -std=c++14`

without and further definition (where `4.8+` means *starting from g++ version 4.8 and onwards*).

Comment: I'm confused.  I don't see how this answers the question `Is there a common way to define, declare and initialize above constexpr such that code compiles successfully by both MSVC and GCC?`  Do you have a way to test it using MSVC?

Comment: @jerry look at OP who says this answer should work in msvc